# Copy a range and shift it down one row on the same sheet

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am fairly new in excel VBA and would really appreciate any help on this matter.

The workbook includes data from range A5:AZ1000 (new client info is inputted in new rows, but some cells may be empty depending on the nature of the case). When a user inputs new client info (begins a new row) I would like the existing data (range A5:AZ1000) to shift down one row, and a blank row to appear in range A5:AZ:5. I would like users to be able to click a macro "New Client" for this to happen.

It should be noted that this is a shared workbook and therefore I cannot have macro that adds a new row.

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
Sub shiftdown()
' shiftdown Macro
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastColumn As Long
Dim rngToCopy As Range
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value
lastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
If rng > 0 Then
     ActiveSheet.Range("A5" & lastRow).Select
     Selection.Copy
     PasteSelection.Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
     'Error Object Required
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Change `PasteSelection.` to `Selection`.  but you should learn to avoid using Select see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros

Comment: Also you can do this as one row inside the IF: `ActiveSheet.Range("A5" & lastRow).Offset(1, 0).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A5" & lastRow).Value` and avoid the clipboard.

Comment: Why did you remove your code?

Comment: @YowE3K it wasn't functional and I thought it might confuse readers of the purpose. I will put it back up.

Comment: The whole purpose (I think) of SO is to turn non-functional code into something that works.  Without code showing, the question will be down-voted into oblivion.

Comment: It is back up. Appreciate your answer all considered.

Comment: I edited the question and rolled it back to Scott's earlier edit, so that the code is formatted nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally I wouldn't answer if the question doesn't include any code to show effort, but I started writing the below while the question actually **did** show code so I may as well provide it.  It may achieve what you are after.

```
Sub shiftdown()
' shiftdown Macro
    Dim rng As Range
    With ActiveSheet
        If .Range("A1").Value > 0 Then

            Set rng = .Range(.Cells(5, 1), _
                             .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, _
                                    .Cells(4, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column))
            rng.Offset(1, 0).Value = rng.Value
            .Rows(5).EntireRow.ClearContents
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks again for your response. The code you provided is moving the data in column A down one row, however, I would need the entire range A5:AZ1000 (last row and column with data) to move down as the macro is clicked and the user may begin to enter new data in row A5:A5. Does this clear the question up for you?

Comment: @ben - Hmmm - for my testing I had data up to column L on row 4 (the one being used to test how many columns to copy) and it moved A5:L21 down to A6:L22.  Does your AZ4 contain anything?

Comment: it seems to be working just fine now! My mistake, the validation I had somehow disappeared. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

`Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value` ???

if rng is a range, then replace it by :

```
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
```

or if rng is a variable, replace

```
Dim rng As Range
```

by

```
Dim rng As variant
rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value
```

another error :

you declared rng as range and then you test if it is > 0

```
If rng > 0 Then ...
```

it is not possible